# Android IME : Hide Row of Symbols

Tags: android, symbols, android-softkeyboard, ime

How can you get rid of the row of symbols at the top of the IME? I mean the row at the top with

!  ?  ,  "  '  :  (  )  -  /

as show below:

[Screenshot http://japan.gadgetmeet.com/uploadfiles/japansemagancom-1313029160/hacker-rsquo-s-keyboard-is-a-full-5-row-on-screen-keyboard-for-android_1.png](http://japan.gadgetmeet.com/uploadfiles/japansemagancom-1313029160/hacker-rsquo-s-keyboard-is-a-full-5-row-on-screen-keyboard-for-android_1.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You write your own IME and convince the user to use it. Or, you convince the user to use some other IME that does not have such symbols (e.g., the Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.0 does not have these symbols).